# Finding the minimum value in one column for all rows for with the same value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, basically I want to find the minimum value in one column for all data points with a specific value in another column. Here are some images for example:

[image]

This is some example data in the format I'm using (there are actually 72 categories, not the 4 shown for example; also there are 308,000 data points).

The desired output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF8mG.png)

In the second column there, I want the lowest value in column F in the first image when the value in column A is A, B, C or D respectively: B2 in the output image should be the minimum Avg (A,B,C,D) for all data points where the reference is A, and so forth. C2 would show the corresponding Value A, D2 Value B, and so on.

So, to give an example: the minimum in column F where the value in column A is B is 0.85. I would want the output to show that in B2. C2 would then be 0.18 - Value A for that datapoint. D2 would be 1.25 - Value B for that datapoint. And so on.

I've messed around with VLOOKUP, INDEX, MIN, IF, etc., but can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any advice?

All the best and many thanks.

[Edit: Updated output specification.]

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not 100% sure of desired outcome this array formula might help:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$308000=Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!A$2:A$308000))
```

To apply this formula you must use **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**.
This one goes to cell `C2` in `Sheet2` and you can stretch it across others.

`Column B` in `Sheet2` would be just `=AVERAGE($C2:$F2)`.

Hope this is the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `A1:F14` *(change as required)* and the output results at `H1:M5` *(change as required)*.

Enter the following `Criteria` in the range `O1:O11`

[image]

Then enter these formulas to obtain the Minimum values by Reference:

in `I2`: `=DMIN($A$1:$F$14,$F$1,$O$1:$O$2)`

in `I3`: `=DMIN($A$1:$F$14,$F$1,$O$4:$O$5)`

in `I4`: `=DMIN($A$1:$F$14,$F$1,$O$7:$O$8)`

in `I5`: `=DMIN($A$1:$F$14,$F$1,$O$10:$O$11)`

Next enter this formula in `J2` and copy it to the range `J2:M5`

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$14,MATCH($I2,$F$1:$F$14,0))
```

[image]

In the case that the Minimum Average value is not unique (see figure below), enter this Formula Array in `J2` and copy it to the range `J2:M5`

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$14,
MATCH($I2,IF($A$1:$A$14<>$H2,0,$F$1:$F$14),0))
```

*Enter the FormulaArray pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{ }` *around the formula if entered correctly*

[image]

For additional explanations please see [WorksheetFunction.DMin Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194945.aspx) and [MS Excel: How to use the DMIN Function (WS)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dmin.php)

Comment: What am I misunderstanding.  I see on your first example that J2 = 1.03.  But doesn't B2 (=0.1) represent the lowest Value A where A is in the Reference Column?  There seem to be other discrepancies also.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The request is to extract the `Minimum Average Value` for each `Reference` and the values associated to it. The `Minimum Average Value` of `A` is `1.2075` and the associated values of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are `1.03`, `0.25`,`2.12` and `1.03` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was interpreting the question differently.